# How to use "old" dependencies with ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core

I've created a new project using a clean install of VS 2015 Enterprise RC1, and I'm trying to add a Nuget package for [Mandrill](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mandrill/) which is built against .NET 4.

When I build the project i get an error from DNX Core 5.0 that the namespace cannot be found:

```
All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
NuGet package restore finished.
1>------ Build started: Project: WebApplication3, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Projects\WebApplication3\src\WebApplication3\MessageServices.cs(5,7,5,15): DNX Core 5.0 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Mandrill' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>
1>  Build failed.
1>           0 Warning(s).
1>           1 Error(s).
1>
1>  Time elapsed 00:00:00.1404086
1>
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Rather than add as a global dependency, I've tried to add it just to the dnx451 framework within `project.json`, with the same result.

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
        "dependencies": {
            "Mandrill": "1.3.1"
        }
    },
    "dnxcore50": { }
},
```

Is it even possible to use .NET 4 packages with ASP.NET 5? If so, what's required?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably the `Mandrill` package doesn't support CoreCLR. You have two options:

1. Remove support for CoreCLR from your package by removing the `dnxcore50` section in `project.json`
2. Use conditional compilation and exclude the calls to the `Mandrill` api. Example: `#if DXNCORE50 ...` or `#if DNX451`